# Reloading rails middleware without restarting the server in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rack, rack-middleware

I have a rails 4 app with middleware located at lib/some/middleware.rb which is currently injected into the stack though an initializer like so:

```
MyApp::Application.configure.do |config|
    config.middleware.use 'Some::Middleware'
end
```

Unfortunately, any time I change something I need to restart the server. How can I reload it on each request in development mode? I've seen similar questions about reloading lib code with either autoloading or wrapping code in a to_prepare block but I'm unsure how that could be applied in this scenario.

Thanks,
- FJM

**Update #1**

If I try to delete the middleware and then re-add it in a to_prepare block I get an error "Can't modify frozen array".

Comment: put your middleware in `app/middlewares` and try again. it's also important to use a string when adding it to the middleware stack and not the class itself as it will not get reloaded otherwise.

Comment: @phoet I tried your suggestion but I was not successful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I thought that at some point Rails was smart enough replacing middleware code at runtime, but I may be wrong.

Here is what I came up with, circumventing Ruby class loading craziness and leveraging Rails class reloading.

Add the middleware to the stack:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
[...]
config.middleware.use "SomeMiddleware", "some_additional_paramter"
```

Make use of auto-reloading, but make sure that the running rails instance and the already initialized middleware object keep "forgetting" about the actual code that is executed:

```
# app/middlewares/some_middleware.rb
class SomeMiddleware
  def initialize(*args)
    @args = args
  end

  def call(env)
    "#{self.class}::Logic".constantize.new(*@args).call(env)
  end

  class Logic
    def initialize(app, additional)
      @app        = app
      @additional = additional
    end

    def call(env)
      [magic]
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

Changes in Logic should be picked up by rails auto reloading on each request.

I think that this actually might become a useful gem!

Comment: That's amazing. What is it about constantizing that causes it to reload?

Comment: I think rails is properly reloading the code, but since the middleware is loaded during initialization, you will have to make sure that the code will get re-evaluated on each request. if you stick to the real class calling `.new` it will have problems, because of the reloading, there are now two `Logic` classes in the object tree. that is not good. so that's why you have to pass the logic to a different class and also don't keep a reference to the class constant.

Comment: @FrankJosephMattia i created an alpha version of a drop-in gem that should take care of reloading in development: https://github.com/phoet/zazicki

Comment: Looks good. I ended up wrapping your original suggestion up into a mixin that I include in my middleware classes. I'll have to give this a shot though.

Answer (score 2):

Building up on @phoet's answer we can actually wrap any middleware with this kind of lazy loading, which I found even more useful:

```
class ReloadableMiddleware
  def initialize(app, middleware_module_name, *middleware_args)
    @app = app
    @name = middleware_module_name
    @args = middleware_args
  end

  def call(env)
    # Lazily initialize the middleware item and call it immediately
    @name.constantize.new(@app, *@args).call(env)
  end
end
```

It can be then hooked into the Rails config with any other middleware as its first argument, given as a string:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use ReloadableMiddleware, 'YourMiddleware'
```

Alternatively - I packaged it into a gem called `reloadable_middleware`, which can be used like so:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use ReloadableMiddleware.wrap(YourMiddleware)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 6 with the new default Zeitwork code loader, this works for me:

```
# at the top of config/application.rb, after Bundler.require    

# Load the middleware. It will later be hot-reloaded in config.to_prepare
Dir["./app/middleware/*.rb"].each do |middleware|
  load middleware
end
```

Below it in the section that configures your `class Application`, add hot-reloading  in `config.to_prepare`:

```
middleware = "#{Rails.root}/app/middleware"
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(middleware)

# Run before every request in development mode, or before the first request in production
config.to_prepare do
  Dir.glob("#{middleware}/*.rb").each do |middleware|
    load middleware
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply use [shotgun](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun)? If I understand your question you want to ensure the environment reloads on every change you make to your code. That is what shotgun will do.

Comment: I looked into shotgun but it appears to reload everything on every request which strikes me as horribly excessive for my needs. I would like to somehow unload and reload my Some::Middleware class the same way my models/controllers are.

Comment: It is horribly excessive conceptually. But in a development context I have found it excellent in actual practise. Since I started using it, it has never noticeably affected performance or introduced any unexpected issues. But yes from a aesthetic point of view it is ugly.