# What is dynamically generated in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What I'm trying to determine is what can be changed on-the-fly in a Rails application w/o restarting the web server.

My assumption is that anything that requires bundler needs restarting and any regular ascii based files (html/css/js) or images can be modified on the fly, but how about:

- /app/controllers/
- /app/models/
- /app/views/
- /config/database.yml

Do any changes to the ruby (*.erb, *.rb) files require a recompile and the web server to be restarted?

Comment: Anything involving structural changes to the database, such as a migration, requires a restart.

Comment: controllers, models and views are all reloaded each request in development; changes to `config/database.yml` require a restart.

Answer (score 1):

There is no strict answer to that question.

In general, Rails tries to reload everything it can without sacrificing development speed.

That is basically everything in `app` and what you define in `config.autoload_paths`.

You can circumvent some restrictions yourself, have a look about how to enable middleware code reloading: [Reloading rails middleware without restarting the server in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874222/reloading-rails-middleware-without-restarting-the-server-in-development/21323432)

Comment: but can you just make changes to a script file w/o having to run any other command? From a PHP and Perl perspective it seems the workflow is more sequential and easier to see how things are generated, but with Rails my understanding is more limited, making the loading/code-sourcing seem more magical.

Comment: i don't understand your question. concerning "magic" rails promises to reload files in app and config.autoload_paths. that's all. everything else you need to take care of yourself.